# Something wrong with recording video and merging audio and video by using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

At the beginning, I have to admit that I am a newbie in FFmpeg and also raspbian. Unfortunately, I need to solve this problem as soon as possible.

I tried to record videos on my Raspberry PI by using PIcamera and USB webcam separately. When I used command:

```
ffmpeg -t 10 -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 out.h264
```

However, something was very wrong because there was nothing saved in that video file. I copy the log.

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x267ad80] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/25 to 1/30
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 37562.908020, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
File 'out.h264' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x267ca60] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6
[libx264 @ 0x267ca60] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2 8-bit
Output #0, h264, to 'out.h264':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.34.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv422p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
DTS 140730117085, next:18648459 st:0 invalid dropping00.00 bitrate=N/A    
PTS 140730117085, next:18648459 invalid dropping st:0
DTS 140740452429, next:6538221 st:0 invalid dropping:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
PTS 140740452429, next:6538221 invalid dropping st:0
frame=   44 fps=1.1 q=28.0 size=      18kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=3712.6kbits/
frame=   45 fps=0.8 q=28.0 size=      22kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=2262.8kbits/
frame=   46 fps=0.7 q=28.0 size=      27kB time=00:00:00.12 bitrate=1813.4kbits/
frame=   47 fps=0.6 q=28.0 size=      30kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=1559.2kbits/
frame=   48 fps=0.5 q=28.0 size=      34kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=1397.7kbits/
frame=   49 fps=0.5 q=28.0 size=      39kB time=00:00:00.24 bitrate=1324.3kbits/
frame=   50 fps=0.4 q=28.0 size=      42kB time=00:00:00.28 bitrate=1241.7kbits/
```

As you can see, the size of each frame was only few kb and fps was so low. Thus each frame was taken by using a long time(4s in this case). Then I test my USB webcam by using command:

```
ffplay -f video4linux2 /dev/video0
```

The video stream which displayed on the screen was so unnatural. It looked like there was such a long delay between each frame. So the video was hardly moved. The log I have copied:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ffplay -f video4linux2 /dev/video0
avplay version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2003-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 31 2013 13:58:10 with gcc 4.6.3
[video4linux2 @ 0x1ad83c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, video4linux2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 36107.154598, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
[avsink @ 0x1ad9960] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x1ad9d20] w:640 h:480 fmt:yuyv422 -> w:640 h:480 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
36163.33 A-V:  0.000 s:0.0 aq=    0KB vq= 3000KB sq=    0B f=8/8
```

The final problem is that no sound was added in video file when I tried to add some in. I used the command:

```
avconv -i /home/pi/Desktop/test.mp4 -i /home/pi/Desktop/test.mp3 -map 0:0 -vcodec copy -map 1:0 -acodec copy output.h264
```

I have checked separately that the video and audio were both able to play. However the merged file only had video but no audio. The log is shown below, it seems that the process was succeed.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ avconv -i /home/pi/Desktop/test.mp4 -i /home/pi/Desktop/test.mp3 -map 0:0 -vcodec copy -map 1:0 -acodec copy output.h264
avconv version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1+rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 31 2013 13:58:10 with gcc 4.6.3
[h264 @ 0x1aa6680] max_analyze_duration reached
[h264 @ 0x1aa6680] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, h264, from '/home/pi/Desktop/test.mp4':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 640x480, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc
[mp3 @ 0x1aaa120] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from '/home/pi/Desktop/test.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : We Are Legend (Original Mix)
    artist          : Dimitri Vegas & Like Mike & Steve Aoki
    album           : SPINNIN RECORDS
    encoded_by      : iTunes 11.1.5
    TBP             : 128
    genre           : Progressive House
    date            : 2013
  Duration: 00:00:11.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 191 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
File 'output.h264' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, h264, to 'output.h264':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 1200k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=  144 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1684kB time=5.06 bitrate=2724.7kbits/s    
video:1566kB audio:119kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000000%
```

Could somebody helps me, please. And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had almost the same issue; I have sound of the first clip of the video, but not others.

However, if I omit the first clip, just merge the others clips, there is video and audio. The difference is that the first clip's audio is merged by two MP3, and does not start at 00:00s.

Comment: Sorry I just saw your post. I have changed my code like this `avconv -i /home/pi/out.mp4 -i /home/pi/Desktop/rectest.m4a -map 0:0 -vcodec mpeg4 -map 1:0 -acodec aac -strict experimental output.mp4`. I used mp4 format for video and m4a for audio. It worked, although synchronization of video and audio was not perfect.